# PHP - Unable to concatenate two variables while generating a php sitemap

Tags: php, dynamic, sitemap, xml-sitemap

while trying to generate dynamic sitemaps, I tried adding two variables in url path, and the line is giving me error

this is my sample line:

```
echo "<loc>" . $base_url . "category.php?category=" . $subFeaturedPostCatSlug . "&job=" . "$subFeaturedPostSlug" . "</loc>" . PHP_EOL;PHP_EOL;
```

I tried doing it like this also:

```
echo "<loc>{$base_url}category.php?category={$subFeaturedPostCatSlug}&job={$subFeaturedPostSlug}</loc>" . PHP_EOL;
```

error screenshot attached;
[image: error screenshot attached]

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: The problem appears to be that you neglected to escape the characters that have special meaning in XML - the `&` being one of them. This is not a PHP error to begin with (not actually _"Unable to concatenate two variables"_), it is an issue of creating incorrect output.

Comment: thanks for answering so quickly @CBroe any idea how to fix this?
because if I remove this & variable the xml is generating just fine

Comment: The `&` needs to be `&amp;` in the resulting XML. You can use `htmlspecialchars` for this, same as you would for HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$str = $base_url . "category.php?category=" . $subFeaturedPostCatSlug . "&amp;job=" . $subFeaturedPostSlug . "" . PHP_EOL;
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this using the `urlencode()` function as mentioned in your comments.

So,

```
echo "<loc>" . $base_url . "category.php?category=" . $subFeaturedPostCatSlug . "&job=" . "$subFeaturedPostSlug" . "</loc>" . PHP_EOL;PHP_EOL;
```

becomes

```
echo "<loc>" . urlencode($base_url) . "category.php?category=" . urlencode($subFeaturedPostCatSlug) . "&job=" . urlencode($subFeaturedPostSlug) . "</loc>" . PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
```

More details at PHP Documentation for [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Also, I found out that there is error in your code:

```
echo "<loc>" . $base_url . "category.php?category=" . $subFeaturedPostCatSlug . "&job=" . "$subFeaturedPostSlug" . "</loc>" . PHP_EOL;PHP_EOL;
```

Towards the end of the `echo`, you have written:

```
...PHP_EOL;PHP_EOL;
```

which should ideally have been

```
...PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
```